# PIVOT SQL with Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have the following table:

```
groupof    dateof                 statusof
A          2020-01-01 00:00:00    YES
A          2020-02-01 00:00:00    NO
A          2020-03-01 00:00:00    YES
B          2020-01-01 00:00:00    YES
```

Then I have the following query:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(dateof) from Table1 group by dateof order by dateof
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT groupof,' + @cols + ' from 
             (select groupof, dateof, statusof from Table1) x
             pivot 
             (count(statusof) for dateof in (' + @cols + ')) p '

execute(@query);
```

The result is:

```
groupof   2020-01-01 00:00:00    2020-02-01 00:00:00    2020-03-01 00:00:00
A         1                      1                      1
B         1                      0                      0
```

I want to have the following result:

```
groupof   2020-JAN     2020-FEB      2020-MAR
A         YES          NO            YES
B         YES          NULL          NULL
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get exact value from `PIVOT` column, use `MAX` aggregate function.
Also, you need to format the `dateof` to get the formatted name of column as you want. You can define any datetime format as you wish. Have a look at more format options [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(FORMAT(dateof, 'yyyy-MMM')) from Table1 group by dateof order by dateof
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT groupof,' + @cols + ' from 
             (select groupof, dateof, statusof from Table1) x
             pivot 
             (MAX(statusof) for dateof in (' + @cols + ')) p '

execute(@query);
```